# Yukawa Potential in non-relativistic limit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

In Peskin's book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory", on page 121 (section 4.7) , it tries to recover the Yukawa Potential in the nonrelativistic limit, but there's a simplification that I don't understant. It says that:
$$
(p'-p)^2=-|{\bf{p'}}-{\bf{p}}|^2+\mathcal{O}({\bf{p}}^4)
$$
where $p'$ and $p$ are the 4-momenta of the incoming particles (and $\bf{p'}$ and $\bf{p}$ are the 3-momenta), both with the same mass $m$.

If I try this expansion, keeping terms only to lowest order, I get:
$$
(p'-p)^2=p'^2-2p'p+p^2=m^2-2(E'E-{\bf |p'||p|})+m^2
$$
Expanding $E=\sqrt{m^2+{\bf |p|}^2}=m+\frac{{\bf |p|}^2}{2m}+\mathcal{O}({\bf{p}}^4)$, I get:
$$
(p'-p)^2=-({\bf |p'|}^2-{\bf |p|}^2)+\mathcal{O}({\bf{p}}^4)
$$
which is clearly different from what the book finds.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: no it doesn't, you made a simple algebra mistake: insertion of your expression for the energy in (p-p')^2  does yield -|p'-p|^2 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four vector $p$ is given as $(E,{\bf p})$ so that

$$(p' -p)^2 = (E' - E)^2 - ({\bf p'} - {\bf p})^2 = (E'^2 - {\bf p'}^2) + (E^2 - {\bf p}^2)- 2E'E + 2 {\bf p'} \cdot {\bf p}$$

Then put $E'E \approx (m + \frac{{\bf p'}^2}{2m})(m + \frac{{\bf p}^2}{2m}) \approx 2m^2 + {\bf p'}^2 + {\bf p}^2$ (ignoring the term $\frac{{\bf p'}^2{\bf p}^2}{4 m^2}$). Using $p'^2 = E'^2- {\bf p'}^2 =  p^2 = E^2- {\bf p}^2 = m^2$ leaves you with $-{\bf p'}^2 +2 {\bf p'} \cdot {\bf p} -{\bf p}^2= -|{\bf p'}-{\bf p}|^2$.